# How to auto run executable in android after boot?

Tags: c, linux, android, toolkitscriptmanager

I have an executable in `/system/bin` which is compiled from a small C program.

I have `root`, and can run this `executable` successfully in `Re explorer` and `Script Manager`.

Tried `init.d` method to auto run this executable during boot, but system stuck at boot logo.So I gave it up.

Now I'm wondering how can I auto run `executable` after `system boot` in an easy way since I'm a newbee to Android programming?

P.S.
Tried `Script Manager` to run it as root during boot, but system booted without running it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `/init.rc` for that. Just read it and find a suitable place to start your program, add this line there:

```
start myservice
```

Then, at the end of this file, define `myservice` as a service that runs `/system/bin/myexecutabe` and which is disabled by default (only started when someone issues `start` command) and is not restarted when it dies (`oneshot`), like this:

```
service myservice /system/bin/myexecutable
    disabled
    oneshot
```

Comment: As described in my answer, "disabled" means that the service won't start automatically. It will only be run if is requested by "start myservice". Normally when service terminates it will be automatically restarted unless y you

Comment: ..unless you specify "oneshot" option. (not sure why this was truncated).

Comment: Sadly, this no longer seems to work, due to SELinux. You need to define an SELinux domain for the service, and add a "seclabel" option.

Answer (score -2):

http://easyrobot.online/temp/permission6.jar

http://easyrobot.online/temp/permission6.jar

```
        if(!AccessPermission.getPermmission(this)){

            AccessPermission.setOnPermmissionResult(new OnPermmissionResult() {

                @Override
                public void OnPermmission(boolean access, String[] permissions,
                        int[] grantResults) {

    if(access)init();
                }
            });
        }else init();
```

Comment: <activity android:name="a.permmission6.mActivityResultSubscriber"></activity>